# adding new child nodes to XML on each function call

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net

I have an XML file and I have a function to which this XML is passed as string. I have loaded this string in Xmldocument and I need to insert few children nodes under one node. This function returns the modified XML string. I want that whenever this function is called, new child nodes are added, currently, It adds child nodes once.

Do I need to overwrite the XML file ? If so, How can I replace the node with new node ( with new child nodes added) so that It has child nodes added before the function is called again ?

My code looks something like this:

```
Dim doc As New XmlDocument
doc.LoadXml(applicationXml)
Dim parentNode As XmlNode = doc.GetElementsByTagName("prList").Item(0)

Dim newElement As XmlNode = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "gate.util.persistence.LanguageAnalyserPersistence", Nothing)

Dim runtimeParamsElement As XmlNode = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "runtimeParams", Nothing)
Dim xa As XmlAttribute = doc.CreateAttribute("class")
xa.Value = "gate.util.persistence.MapPersistence"
runtimeParamsElement.Attributes.Append(xa)

localMapElement = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "localMap", Nothing)
featuresElement.AppendChild(localMapElement)

newElement.AppendChild(featuresElement)

Return doc.InnerXml
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not showing enough code to determine the exact problem. Which node are you trying to replace? Where did featuresElement come from? Here are a few answers:

1. Yes you need to replace the whole file using the new document.
2. You don't need to replace the node with a new node. Just pass the target node to your function. The function should call appendChild() on the parent node to add a child.
3. When you write the document to file, [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.save%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), it will have the new nodes.